# Expand a variable whose value contains an option and a pathname with whitespaces

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

```
$ md="-l /tmp/test/my dir"
$ ls "$md"
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.

$ md="-l \"/tmp/test/my dir\""
$ ls "$md"
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

I was wondering why both don't work? Thanks.
Note that the value of the variable contains

- an option `-l`
- a pathname argument which contains a space
- a space which separates the above two.

---

My actual problem is: I wrote a script `myscript.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

old_dest=""
while getopts ":l:t" opt; do
    case $opt in
        l)
            old_dest="--link-dest \"$OPTARG\""
            ;;
    esac
done

rsync -a --delete "$old_dest" /path/to/source  /path/to/dest
```

I want to call the script as a command with `-l` option.

```
myscript.sh -l "/media/t/my external hdd/backup/old one"
```

How should I write the part of the script which assigns to `old_dest`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Hold multiple space containing arguments in a single variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342537/hold-multiple-space-containing-arguments-in-a-single-variable)

Comment: [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350)  The second section is exactly the same as what you’re doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your command doesn't work is because quote removal/word splitting is not applied recursively.

So `"$old_dest"` is expanded to the SINGLE argument that follows:

```
--link-dest "/media/t/my external hdd/backup/old one"
```

All that is ONE argument, because the variable was in double quotes.  (And those double quotes are removed, but the double quotes that *resulted from the expansion*, i.e. were part of the variable value, are not removed.)

If you used `$old_dest` instead, you would get multiple arguments, but not the way you want.  You'd get the following FIVE arguments:

```
--link-dest
"/media/t/my
external
hdd/backup/old
one"
```

This is because you would get variable expansion followed by word splitting, as covered in the manual.  You would *not* get variable expansion followed by interpretation of the quotes in the variable.  And the quotes would not be removed, so the final argument would be the four characters: `one"`.

The right way to do it, as covered in another answer, is to use Bash arrays.

---

On a separate note, you might enjoy how Tcl handles quotes and word splitting.  It's probably more intuitive, although I'm so practiced with shell word splitting I have to think more about Tcl than shell.

Comment: Thanks. In `ls: invalid option -- ' '` of the output of my first example, why does it mention `' '`?

Comment: @Tim, that almost warrants its own question, but here's a brief answer: by convention for most tools, options are either one hyphen and one letter or two hyphens and a human readable name.  Multiple one-letter options can be combined by placing all such letters after the same hyphen; e.g. `ls -laht` is the same as `ls -l -a -h -t`.  There is no `-<space>` option, though—and your first example has a literal space character amongst the characters all in the same argument following the single hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using bash, and since bash supports arrays, I would suggest making old_dest an array, instead:

```
#! /bin/bash

old_dest=()
while getopts ":l:t" opt; do
    case $opt in
        l)
            old_dest+=('--link-dest' "$OPTARG")
            ;;
    esac
done

printf 'Element: %s\n' rsync -a --delete "${old_dest[@]}" /path/to/source  /path/to/dest
```

I instrumented the call to rsync to instead be a call to printf to show the command and each argument on a separate line. When executed:

```
./myscript.sh -l "/media/t/my external hdd/backup/old one"
```

The result is:

```
Element: rsync
Element: -a
Element: --delete
Element: --link-dest
Element: /media/t/my external hdd/backup/old one
Element: /path/to/source
Element: /path/to/dest
```

Comment: Thanks. Manpage of rsync says `--link-dest=DIR`, so I think I made a mistake in my post. I am not sure how you manage to run rsync with `--link-dest DIR`.

Comment: Your reply indeed works, if it were `--link-dest DIR`. I have figured out solution for `--link-dest=DIR`. Thank you.

Comment: I didn’t run anything except printf, since I don’t have your environment. I just copied the command you have.